solutions to Hung-Hsi Wu's Teaching School Mathematics: Prealgebra/Algebra textbooks?
I am currently home-schooling my kids and picking up the math subjects that have long been neglected by me.
I have been looking for solutions to Hung-Hsi Wu's <Teaching School Mathematics: Prealgebra/Algebra> textbooks, but couldn't find them. Any help would be appreciated.

If you can't solve the problems you are assigning, you shouldn't be teaching because you aren't even minimally qualified to do so. Find someone professional and qualified to educate your children. Imagine a piano teacher who can't play basic etudes.

I disagree with Dan Fox. Wu's books are not easy to read, and the exercises are not all easy either, as they may ask you to explain a concept in a way that you are not familiar with (even if it is the "proper" way from an axiomatic approach to the content: kids don't naturally learn maths through an axiomatic approach!). OP - I would recommend the book "making every maths lesson count" by Emma McCrea. Maybe come back to Wu later if you find time.
